# SQL command not properly ended or invalid identifier

Tags: sql, oracle

Unable to determine why this query is causing an exception. any help is appreciated.

ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

`SELECT COUNT(sd.URI) AS OrchCount FROM  SDETAIL AS sd, ORCH_ASSOC  AS orch WHERE sd.uri=orch.OPERATION_ AND sd.LEVEL='OrchA'`

```
SELECT COUNT(SDETAIL.URI) AS OrchCount FROM SDETAIL WHERE SDETAIL.URI=ORCH_ASSOC.OPERATION_ AND SDETAIL.COMPONENTLEVEL='OrchA'
```

ORA-00904: "ORCH_ASSOC"."OPERATION_": invalid identifier

Comment: Please show ALL relevant details - like the table schemas in question. Edit your original question with the addtional details. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

The `AS` keyword is only used in assigning column aliases, not tables:

```
FROM SDETAIL AS sd, ORCH_ASSOC AS orch
```

You can leave out `AS` and it should work fine:

```
FROM SDETAIL sd, ORCH_ASSOC orch
```

Comment: smacks head.. Thanks willOEM that did it.

Answer (score 0):

@clav is right about the ORA-00904. As for the ORA-00933, that's because you did this:

```
... FROM SDETAIL AS sd
```

Do this instead (no "as"):

```
... FROM SDETAIL sd
```

Comment: Glad to hear it! @willOEM had the same answer and answered first, so can you mark the willOEM post as the correct answer? It will help anyone else who ends up with a similar problem to see which solution worked.